# How to add a custom kernel flavour?

Tags: kernel, compiling, linux-headers

For multiple reasons, I need to build a custom kernel for an otherwise standard x86 Ubuntu 16.04 system. Following [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), I succeeded in building the suite of packages I need with the following invocation:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch skipdbg=false do_tool=true
```

However, as a next step in this effort I am wondering about doing some things like trimming back the number of unneeded drivers, including some patches which I otherwise currently install using dh_dkms packages, etc. I feel that even for my own use, it would be best if these changes could be published internally not under the standard "generic" name but perhaps a new flavour/config that is specific to my company's semi-embedded use case.

I'm finding the Ubuntu kernel repos (eg git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-disco.git) a bit hard to navigate, though, and it appears to be sufficiently diverged from how Debian does it that their docs on kernel building aren't super helpful either.

So my question is: Where are the flavours and their configs (or config defaults) defined in this repo? It looked like it might have been in `debian.master/control.d/vars.<flavourname>`, but adding a new file there didn't make a `binary-<flavourname>` build target available, and didn't change anything about how `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` behaved either.

Thanks.

Comment: That is a really complicated action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out not to be too difficult in the end. For future travelers, these files need to be created—start out by basing them on the `generic` ones in the same directories:

- `debian.master/config/amd64/config.flavour.<flavour>`
- `debian.master/control.d/<flavour>.inclusion-list`
- `debian.master/control.d/vars.<flavour>`

And then the following two files need minor edits to specify building only the `amd64` arch and just the new flavour name (instead of `generic lowlatency`):

- `debian.master/etc/kernelconfig`
- `debian.master/rules.d/amd64.mk`

With these changes, you can:

```
fakeroot debian/rules genconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules binary skipabi=true skipmodule=true skipretpoline=true skipdbg=true
```

And you'll get a suite of working kernel packages with `x.y.z-<flavour>` release name.